# Similar splice in C++ like the splice in Javascript?

Tags: c++, sdl, splice

is there a similar method/function in C++ like the splice in Javascript?

Example from W3School:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2,1,"Lemon","Kiwi");
```

The result of fruits will be:
Banana,Orange,Lemon,Kiwi,Mango

I wan't to be able to do the same thing in C++. I have created an array of boxes that should dissapear one by one when I click on them. I don't know how to do it, please help.

PS. I'm using the SDL library and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: yes - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a vector, you have access to the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"};
    auto pos = fruits.begin() + 2;

    fruits.insert(pos, {"Lemon", "Kiwi"});

    for (auto fruit : fruits) std::cout << fruit << " ";
}
```

> Output: Banana Orange Lemon Kiwi Apple Mango

[Here is a Demo.](http://ideone.com/xVpZn1#view_edit_box)

Comment: std::vector<std::string> fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"}; //Error: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "std::vector<std::string, std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>"

for (auto fruit : fruits) //Error: cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)

Sorry, but I need more help. YES, it was a long time since I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
vector<T> splice(vector<T>& v, int start, int howmuch, const vector<T>& ar) {
    vector<T> result(begin(v) + start, begin(v) + start + howmuch);
    v.erase(begin(v) + start, begin(v) + start + howmuch);
    v.insert(begin(v) + start, begin(ar), end(ar));
    return result;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"};
    auto v = splice(fruits, 2, 1, {"Lemon", "Kiwi"});

    cout << "Returned value: " << endl;
    for (auto &s: v) {
        cout << "\t" << s << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "fruits: " << endl;
    for (auto &s: fruits) {
        cout << "\t" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
Returned value: 
    Apple

fruits: 
    Banana
    Orange
    Lemon
    Kiwi
    Mango
```

It's a templated version so it should work not only with strings;
Function behaves the same as JS version but you have to pass your vector as the first parameter here.

Comment: This doesn't work sorry, and when lokking at the other answer: std::vector<std::string> fruits = {"Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"}; //Error: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "std::vector<std::string, std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>" for (auto fruit : fruits) //Error: cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required) Sorry, but I need more help. YES, it was a long time since I asked the question.

Comment: @LucasJohansson, I understand your problem. Here we use C++11 and your compiler uses C++03 by default. Change settings to C++11 - if your compiler is gcc/clang just add `-std=c++11` flag. If you use MSVC look at the project options

Comment: Thanks for helping. I don't exacly know what gcc/clang is, so I don't think I use it. I tried looking for a compiler option (Alt + F7) in my project but couldn't find any. Sorry, but I need more detailed help. The good thing is that if I learn this now I won't need to ask about it again. This will make the process of my future projects a lot faster.